# [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'abcdef'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, python-2.7, azure-sql-database, pyodbc

```
ownerpass="abcdef"
owner="yrdy"
sql_login = (
"DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);"
"DECLARE @Databaseowner sysname = ?;"
"DECLARE @Databaseownerpass sysname = ?;"
"SET @sql = N'if not exists (select * from sys.sql_logins where name = @Databaseowner )'  + N' CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseowner) + N''' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseownerpass, '''') + N';';"
"EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@Databaseowner sysname', N'@Databaseownerpass sysname', @Databaseowner = @Databaseowner, @Databaseownerpass = @Databaseownerpass;")
cursor.execute(sql_login, owner,ownerpass)
=============================================
```

Getting incorrect syntax error near password

Comment: `N''' WITH PASSWORD` should be `N' WITH PASSWORD`.

Comment: And `"EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@Databaseowner sysname', N'@Databaseownerpass sysname', @Databaseowner = @Databaseowner, @Databaseownerpass = @Databaseownerpass;")` should be `"EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Databaseowner sysname, @Databaseownerpass sysname', @Databaseowner, @Databaseownerpass;"`

Comment: pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', u'[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Procedure or function  has too many arguments specified. (8144) (SQLExecDirectW)') getting this error
 N'if not exists (select * from sys.sql_logins where name = @Databaseowner )'  + N' CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseowner) + N' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseownerpass, '''') + N';';"

Comment: @AzarManiyar Try to execute statement like this: `"EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Databaseowner sysname, @Databaseownerpass sysname', @Databaseowner, @Databaseownerpass;"`

Comment: Yes tried Got the same error

Comment: @AzarManiyar Your statement should work even with this call: `EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Databaseowner sysname',  @Databaseowner;`, because you try to concatenate `@Databaseownerpass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, generate valid T-SQL statement. Your have errors when you use [CREATE LOGIN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
ownerpass = "abcdef"
owner = "yrdy"
sql_login = (
    "DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);"
    "DECLARE @Databaseowner sysname = ?;"
    "DECLARE @Databaseownerpass sysname = ?;"
    "SET @sql = 
        N'if not exists (select * from sys.sql_logins where name = @Databaseowner )'  + 
        N' CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseowner) + 
        N' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseownerpass, '''') + N';';"
    "EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@Databaseowner sysname, @Databaseownerpass sysname', @Databaseowner, @Databaseownerpass;"
)
```

Then, if you use `?` as a placeholder, execute your script like this:

```
cursor.execute(sql_login, (owner, ownerpass))
```

Answer (score 1):

According what I found, if your sql statement has parameters, you should modify you code like this:

```
ownerpass="abcdef"
owner="yrdy"
sql_login = (
"DECLARE @sql AS NVARCHAR(MAX);"
"DECLARE @Databaseowner sysname = ?;"
"DECLARE @Databaseownerpass sysname = ?;"
"SET @sql = N'if not exists (select * from sys.sql_logins where name = @Databaseowner )'  + N' CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseowner) + N''' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseownerpass, '''') + N';';"
"EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@Databaseowner sysname', N'@Databaseownerpass sysname', @Databaseowner = @Databaseowner, @Databaseownerpass = @Databaseownerpass;")
cursor.execute(sql_login, (owner,ownerpass))
```

Reference: [(Python) cursor.execute(sql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36153206/python-cursor-executesql)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

"SET @sql = N'if not exists (select * from sys.sql_logins where name = @Databaseowner )'  + N' CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseowner) + N''' WITH PASSWORD = ' + QUOTENAME(@Databaseownerpass, '''') + N';';"

how can I add check_policy= off in above line ?